# Does redirecttoaction use the same server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If I'm scaling the web app server horizontally with trying to avoid using sessions, but I need to use `TempData` with `RedirectToAction`. TempData uses sessions for 1 round trip. Does the RedirectToAction go to the browser then back to the server or it redirects internally?

Reason for question, I may loose the session if the redirect hits another server instead of the original server the session was created on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RedirectToAction just issues a response redirect to the browser so yes it does do a round trip so you do risk losing your session (unless you use a session aware load balancer).